# how to set the all my option as selected by default and all option values should be displayed in the field in react select in multiselect

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-select-search, react-multiselect-checkboxes

```
<Select
        components={animatedComponents}
        isMulti
        defaultValue={selectedClassOptions}
        value={selectedClassOptions}
        options={classOptions}
        onChange={(item) => setSelectedClassOptions(item)}
        className="generalSelect"
        isClearable={false}
        isSearchable={false}
        isDisabled={false}
        isLoading={false}
        isRtl={false}
        closeMenuOnSelect={false}
        placeholder="Class"
        styles={{
          option: (provided, state) => ({
            ...provided,
            borderBottom: "1px solid #F9F9F9",
            padding: "10px 15px", // Adjust padding as needed
            backgroundColor: state.isSelected ? "#f7f7f7" : "unset",
          }),
          menu: (provided, state) => ({
            ...provided,
            padding: "10px",
            zIndex: 9999,
            borderRadius: "10px", // Adjust z-index as needed
          }),
          placeholder: (provided, state) => ({
            ...provided,
            color: "#a8a8a8",
          }),
        }}
      />  

 <Select
        isMulti
        defaultValue={selectedOptions}
        value={selectedOptions}
        options={optionsMulti}
        onChange={(item) => setSelectedOptions(item)}
        className="select"
        isClearable={false}
        isSearchable={false}
        isDisabled={false}
        isLoading={false}
        isRtl={false}
        closeMenuOnSelect={false}
        // value={optionsMulti}
        placeholder="Student"
        styles={{
          option: (provided, state) => ({
            ...provided,
            borderBottom: "1px solid #F9F9F9",
            padding: "10px 15px", // Adjust padding as needed
            backgroundColor: state.isSelected ? "#f7f7f7" : "unset",
          }),
          menu: (provided, state) => ({
            ...provided,
            padding: "10px",
            borderRadius: "10px",
            zIndex: 9999, // Adjust z-index as needed
          }),
          placeholder: (provided, state) => ({
            ...provided,
            color: "#a8a8a8",
          }),
        }}
      />
```

Here I will select the class based on that class I will get the students option dynamically and I want to whenever I select the class the students option will be generated by default that all options should be selected in and values displayed in this another multiselect in this multiselect how to do that defaultValue={selectedClassOptions} is not worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Select
  components={animatedComponents}
  isMulti
  defaultValue={selectedStudentOptions} // defaultValue to selectedStudentOptions
  options={selectedStudentOptions} // Use the selected options
  onChange={(selectedStudents) => setSelectedStudentOptions(selectedStudents)}
  className="generalSelect"
  isClearable={false}
  isSearchable={false}
  isDisabled={false}
  isLoading={false}
  isRtl={false} 
  placeholder="Students"
  styles={{
    option: (provided, state) => ({
      ...provided,
      borderBottom: "1px solid #F9F9F9",
      padding: "10px 15px",
      backgroundColor: state.isSelected ? "#f7f7f7" : "unset",
    }),
    menu: (provided, state) => ({
      ...provided,
      padding: "10px",
      zIndex: 9999,
      borderRadius: "10px",
    }),
    placeholder: (provided, state) => ({
      ...provided,
      color: "#a8a8a8",
    }),
  }}
/>
```

By making this modification, the student options that were first chosen will be the defaultValue of the second Select component, making them pre-selected when the component renders.

Comment: value={selectedOptions} why you removed this and what this will do   onChange={(selectedStudents) => setSelectedStudentOptions(selectedStudents)}